# Equality vs. Bicondition in Z3

Tags: logic, z3, smt

I'm trying to understand the difference in Z3 between equality testing and biconditional. My understanding is that `=` is used to express biconditional, but how is equality tested?

For example. I am trying to write something similar to the following (toy) statement in z3:

`on_table(o, a) ↔ (in_hand(o) Λ a != pickup(o)) ∨ a = put_on_table(o)`

Note: I am aware the above statement can be factored into a set of implications, but I am interested in expressing it as a single biconditional.

Answer (score 3):

For the `Bool` type, equality and biconditional are the same operations. For any other type, biconditional doesn't really make sense.

All logics in SMT come equipped with the notion of equality, which is essentially term-level equality of objects. The standard explicitly states:

> Version 2.6 of the SMT-LIB format adopts as its underlying logic a
>   version of many-sorted first-order logic with equality [Man93, Gal86,
>   End01].

See Section 2.2 of http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf

The same document also says (Section 3.7.1):

> Note the absence of a symbol for double implication. Such a connective
>   is superfluous because the equality symbol = can be used in its place.

I suspect though, perhaps, you are trying to ask for something else. Some further examples would definitely help.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't clear from my original example, but `a` represents a sort, of which `pickup(o)` and `put_on_table(o)` are instances of that sort. Let me try to formulate the question into a more specific example.